# Click help not coming up

Tags: python, python-click

I have a click CLI that will not pop up the built in help menu. What it does is runs the code I have even when inputting 'python file.py --help'. No help menu pops up and for some reason the code goes runs. I do not want the code to run I want the help menu to pop open. Any help with this would be appreciated.

Here is the code. I can not include everything:

def main():

```
@click.command()
@click.option('--run_name', help='Name of the run being permformed')
@click.option('--run_file', help='Name of the file on computer needed')
@click.option('--description', help='Brief description of run')
def register(run_name, run_file, description):
    ''' 
    Register a new run
    '''

#Allow user to enter run_name, run_file, descrption and also allow user to confirm if they want to continue 
run_name = click.prompt('Please enter a run name', type=str)
run_file = click.prompt('Please enter a file name', type=str)
description = click.prompt('Please enter file description', type=str)
click.confirm('Do you want to continue?', abort=True)
```

Comment: Can you edit with the code you use so that we can check what is wrong with it ?

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

```
import click

@click.command()
@click.option('--count', default=1, help='Number of greetings.')
@click.option('--name', prompt='Your name',
              help='The person to greet.')
def hello(count, name):
    """Simple program that greets NAME for a total of COUNT times."""
    for x in range(count):
        click.echo(f"Hello {name}!")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    hello()
```

Should generate this help message.

```
Usage: click_test.py [OPTIONS]

  Simple program that greets NAME for a total of COUNT times.

Options:
  --count INTEGER  Number of greetings.
  --name TEXT      The person to greet.
  --help           Show this message and exit.
```

Comment: you need to execute the above code as "python click_test.py --help" to see the complete options menu

Answer (score 0):

You may also provide the option `no_args_is_help=True` to your `@click.command`.
Using this option the help message will be displayed when you run your tool without any arguments.

```
import click


@click.command("my_tool", no_args_is_help=True)
@click.option("-c", "--config", help="An argument..")
def run(config):
    print(config)
```

This way either `python cow_client.py` or `python cow_client.py --help` will display the help message.

```
python my_tool.py
    Usage: my_tool.py [OPTIONS]

    Options:
        -c, --config TEXT  An argument..
        --help             Show this message and exit.
```

Answer (score -1):

Try running `python -m your_script.py --help`, that should work.

Alternatively, use Poetry or another build tool to build your package and install it to a venv, then run the script from there with your entry point enabled.